# How to get Convert DC to AC for higher frequency with H-Bridge?

Tags: power, inverter, h-bridge, dc-ac

Require High Frequency AC supply (**300 V, 1-2 kHz**), as of my knowledge increasing frequency AC-AC is hard compare to DC-AC. So I decided to input DC and get AC of 300 V, 1-2 kHz.

Please help how to archive this with H-Bridge, or in any other way.

Whole goal is to send (300 V, 1-2 kHz) through 24AWG wire for 120 meters and rectify to DC at the load(**14 V, 40 A (avg)**).

Edit-1( More info)

My load amps draw may vary upto DC 14 V, 70 A(max), I am using 12AWG wire to power the load, but it weighs more, I want to decrease the weight of wire, so I thought to add a rectifier at the load, so that i can send supply through 24AWG (or suitable gauge depends on amps,significant weight less compare to 12AWG wire weight.

Ref:- projectappa.weebly.com

Comment: Christ almighty! Capital I for I. Sentences start with capital letter. No space before comma. Space after comma. kHz for kilohertz. Simple stuff really.

Answer (score 1):

Your load takes 14 volts and consumes up to 40 amps. That's a power of 560 watts. 24 AWG cable is not recommended for power transmission at current levels greater than 0.58 amps (see [this table](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm)). Playing safe I would not want to be feeding more than 0.5 amps through the cable and, at this level of current, to deliver 560 watts, the voltage needs to be 1120 volts and this doesn't include the efficiency of the transformer and regulator (maybe 85%) So, a voltage of more like 1300 volts is in the right ball park.

> Whole goal is to send (300v 1-2Khz) through 24AWG wire for 120Meters
>   and rectify to DC at the load(14v,40Amps).

You are way-off the mark here - you need a peak voltage that is in the realm of 1300 volts and this is at the load end.

The resistance of 24 AWG wire is 85 ohms per km or 10.2 ohms per 120 metres but, you need a forward and return path so that's around 20 ohms and the volt drop at 0.5 amps (plus another 10% to power the inefficiences of the transformer and regulator) is 11 volts.

This means that the voltage generator at the sending end has to be a bit more than 1300 volts. I would aim to produce 1400 volts peak. I would also check to see if the 24 AWG cable you are intending to use has the correct insulation qualities for this level of voltage. If it hasn't then you are dead in the water and you might as well replace the cable with something more substantial than can deliver a few amps thus requiring a much smaller peak voltage at the generating end.

Comment: Andy aka ,

i am using silicone wire (aluminium) 
from https://oscarliang.com/wire-awg-chart-quadcopter-rc/ 24awg permissible amps is 5Amps .If it allows 5amp i can send 120 volts right ?(glad to your response and time)

Comment: More info Andy aka,

My load amps draw may vary upto DC 14v,70Amp(max),I am using 12AWG Wire to power the load, but it weighs more,i want to decrease the weight of wire,so i thought to add a rectifier at the load, So that i can send supply through 24AWG(or suitable gauge depends on amps ,weighs less compare to 12awg wire weight.

Ref:- projectappa.weebly.com

Comment: @ChaitanyaKrishna:  The resistivity of Aluminum is about 1.7 times that of copper, so your Al wire will have a resistance of about 34 Ohms, rather than the 20 Ohms Andy calculated for copper.

Comment: @Peter Bennett,glad for your response,
So you are telling that voltage drop will increase across the 24AWG wire of 34 ohms to copper of 20ohms?

but if the 5amp of aluminium wire is true then it reduces the voltage requirement of 1400volts to 120volts(with losses it would be 200-300volts) .So i am thinking aluminum(silicone) wire is better,correct me if i went wrong.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKrishna: no.  Aluminum wire has higher resistance, so more voltage drop and more heating of the wire.  Also, I think the current rating shown on the oscarliang site are extremely optimistic, even for copper wire.  For house wiring in North America, we only allow 15 amps for #14 where his first table says 55 Amp.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKrishnademonstrate that the current thru the wire can be greater than 0.5 amps please.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, changing the frequency of AC is harder than just turning DC into AC, but from what you've said I can't see why AC is useful to you. It seems your goal is to lower the current in the wires so you can use thinner wire. Couldn't you just increase the DC voltage with a boost converter?

If not, then what you're trying to do is design an **inverter**. An inverter is essentially a H-bridge with a low pass filter on the output. You'll need the H-bridge and the low pass filter, some gate drivers for the H-bridge, and a method for controlling the gate drivers. Designing an inverter is no small effort.

Comment: With the power requirement needed and the low current that can be safely fed down the wire, the voltage needed to drive the wire is in excess of 1300 volts. Given what I've said, it makes sense not to use DC but use AC and transformer the voltage down at the receiving end.

Comment: Okay, but AC doesn't let you bypass the power law. Power is still voltage times current, in DC and in AC. So AC wont significantly change the voltages and currents involved.